# Landsat Collection 1 Level-1 or Landsat Collection 1 Higher Level?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, ndvi, landsat-8, landsat-7

I want to use NDWI and NDVI index in my study for a time-series analysis using all products available (Landsat 5,7 and 8).

Can I use the product Landsat Collection 1 Level 1 for my analysis or 
should I use Landsat Collection 1 Higher Level?

My doubt is because the calibration that use Landsat Collection 1 Level 1 is regardless of the sensor and the indexes that I want to use are dimensionless, however, always in this kind of studies we use surface reflectance (Landsat Collection 1 Higher Level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a paper that answered totally my question. I recommend  this paper, especially for those who are just starting to use Landsat  images. This is a very good and updated summary of the last products of Landsat and a great guide for common uses in ecology studies.

Paper: Young et al. (2017). A survival guide to Landsat preprocessing.